# How to update data in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have to update data in the data base. Data is shown in text boxes wen i select a data grid-view row. where am i wrong??

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ent = new EmployeeEntities();

        EmployeeInfo emp = new EmployeeInfo();
        emp.EmpID = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);
        emp.EmpName = txtName.Text;
        emp.EmpAddress = txtAddress.Text;
        emp.EmpDesignation = txtDesignation.Text;
        //ent.EmployeeInfoes.Add(emp);
        ent.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Updated");

}
```

Comment: you forgot to retrieve data to update it

Comment: Please don't post same question again and again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192045/updating-data-in-gridview

Answer (score 2):

The entity/ies you wish to save have to be attached to a data context in order to be saved upon calling SaveChanges. If calling `ent.SaveChanges()` calls the context's `SaveChanges()` then you only have to use `ent.EmployeeInfoes.Add(emp);`. If not, you need to retrieve the `EmployeeEntities` from the database first and then add the `EmployInfo`.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
EmployeeInfo emp = new EmployeeInfo();
```

by

```
int empId=Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);
EmployeeInfo emp =ent.EmployeeInfoes.Single(e=>e.EmpId==empId);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to add emp as a new emplouee, try

```
ent.EmployeeInfoes.AddObject(emp);
ent.SaveChanges();
```

else you must get emp from the list of employees then save it